# Info button ( i )

Tags: button, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create an info button (the one that is round with an i in the middle) to appear on the right side of the navigation bar. I have seen the examples in the demo page of KendoUI mobile section and I see a button saying "Index" on the right side of some screens. Instead of displaying a button with a text inside, I would like to display the info button. Is that part of the KendoUI framework that I could just name that class and it will display that info button?  If not, if I have the image, how will I be able to put that inside a button and that it will look good in iOS, Android and Windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Kendo UI mobile framework itself.

If you want use 'info button' inside navigation bar then 
you should use 'detailbutton' concept.

look at the following code

```
......
<div data-role="navbar">
     <a data-role="detailbutton" data-icon="info" title="info button"></a>
</div>
.....
```

It will display a button as you said.(Button that is round with an 'i' symbol in the middle)

It will work on all the platforms that Kendo UI supports